# Using tkinter's button and entry widgets to update instance variable

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to implement a little application that logs in a user and the user after log in can add/update/delete contents to/of a textfile. Here's a rough sketch of the code I have so far:

```
class admin():
        def __init__(self):

                self.app = Tk()
                .
                self.name=StringVar()
                update = Button(self.app,....,command=self.update)
                .
                .
                .

        def update():
                #Function to take different entries using Entry widget of tkinter in another window
                anotherapp = Tk()
                nameentry = Entry(anotherapp,textvariable = self.name)
                submitbutton = Button(anotherapp,....,command=submit)
                .
                .

        def submit():
                #Opens a file and adds entries to a textfile. 
                namevar = self.name.get()
                # code to append to file
```

To explain the above, I have a class admin. Creating an instance of this class would open a window with buttons that say create, update, delete and so on. On clicking one of the buttons, the respective functions (defined in the same class) would be called (I use `lambda:` in case the function has arguments, but so far, it doesn't).

So in the code I've mentioned, say I click on the Update button, it should call the update function which opens another window and takes the text that has to be updated in the text file (via the Entry widget). So according to the code it'll update the value of name. On clicking submit, the function submit uses `.get()` to get the string value of name, and appends it to the text file.

The code executes with no error but it DOES NOT read the input from the user. Blank lines get appended to my textfile when I click on the submit button.

Now I don't understand why this isn't working. The `name` variable is defined in **init** and can be updated by the functions of the same class. I have tried a lot of things to make this work, including adding parameters in the button commands, defining `name` elsewhere, etc. Even though I've solved the error, I get the same result: the file gets appended with blank lines. I've also tried to make name a class variable but that doesn't work since it is declared using StringVar() which needs it to be part of a tkinter window. I think I've also tried nesting `submit` function inside the `update` function, but I don't know why that didn't work out or if I hadn't implemented it correctly.

I don't know if it has to do with the working of tkinter's `StringVar()` and `.get()` function.

I can't think of any other way to implement the situation I have at hand. I am open to taking suggestions on changing the structure of the code, as long as it is not something major major and manages to achieve the functionality that I've described.

I am sorry if I've missed something basic, cause I've only started trying out OOP in python recently. And thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: first of don't use two instances of `Tk()` instead use Toplevel for any new windows. second: with entry there its own `.get()` function: `entry_instance.get()` (which makes me think if Entry even has a textvariable but maybe it does) also are You using this StringVar for anything else in the code (like other widgets)

Comment: also defining methods in classes requires `self` argument unless decorated with `@staticmethod` that may also be the issue so when defining a method use `def method_name(self):` it will also help access self. attributes. also You have to call self. methods with the `self.` like so `self.method_name()` so in the `command=` kwarg for button You would define `command=self.method_name`

Comment: I've used StringVar in the __init__ function and in one function outside the class but those are for separate tkinter windows

Comment: Could You try printing `namevar` before it gets appended to the file and also add `self` to the other methods (`method_name(self):`) oh and You are not using the same StringVar for the other widget? also try `self.nameentry` and then acces that byt `self.nameentry.get()` and see if You get anything then